# Console application accept command from web

Tags: c#

I am in the early stages of making a command line application, and came to think of that it would be nice if it could also hook up a http listeners to a random available port and display a very simple webform, containint 2 textboxes and 3 buttons.

One textbox should be for command input, underneath it two of the three buttons "Clear" and "Run".

Underneath those buttons should be the scond textbox, showing the result aswell as the last button to clear that textbox.

I have been searching google for a couple of hours now for some good examples or guides, but I just can't find any.

Is there anyone here who might have some examples or could point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Comment: Consider Nancy (http://nancyfx.org/), which can be self hosted in a console application, or can run on a ready made web server.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get away from trying to make one "application" that does both console and web and instead think of it as an architecture of components that serve everything.

Make a shared library that has your core functionality.

Then make a console application that exposes this functionality over the console.

Finally make a web application that exposes the functionality over the web.

Separating them this way will vastly simplify your task and is the right thing to do.

Comment: I think the OP's point is that he doesn't want (might not even have) a Web server. So he wants his console application to serve Web requests. Seems reasonable. That's what `HttpListener` is for.

Comment: @JimMischel That is exactly the point. I have been looking at HttpListener and now also at Nancy, but I just can't make anything of it. Especially with nancy I don't find any examples or documentation on how to achieve what I want.

Comment: re: nancy: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Self-Hosting-Nancy, http://codebetter.com/brendantompkins/2013/01/15/fun-with-the-nancy-self-host/, and google in general